# How to change margin width of iBooks in macOS

Tags: macos, books

Is it possible to change the margin width in iBooks in macOS? I'm attaching a screenshot wherre I've marked the width with red arrow. My question is can  I shorten or widen the left/right margins?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to change the margin width in iBooks in macOS

The margin width is not user customizable in iBooks for macOS.

> My question is can I shorten or widen the left/right margins?

The margin width is dynamically adjusted (while keeping both left and right margin equal) based on the window and the font size. You can play around with it to suit your preference.

The window size is preserved on per book basis. (Different books can have different window size, which is restored when opening the book)

Comment: It's true and it's unfortunate. There is no way to change the margins in the Books app for Mac. I set the Books window to 8" total width, and it uses 1.5" of the space for margins on each side (3" total) - over 30% of horizontal space wasted. Terrible.